# How do I use FCM with codeigniter sql webpage?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a notification features on my android apps using firebase FCM on a sql db. My question is, I have a web page for admin to input the data. Is it possible to have whenever the admin updated the data, it would notify all the user's device? If so how do I do it? I am using codeigniter for the webpage.

I am still a beginner in programming and would appreciate all the help you guys can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to receive msg-notification from firebase, you have to do some 2 steps :

1. Using your web-admin page to send msg to FCM backend using Firebase Admin SDK.
2. Register user'device with google FCM backend.